# Plot colored rectangles using a loop on a spectrum using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I need to plot a large number of colored rectangles on a spectrum. To do this I read in an excel files of spectrum lines and use `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` and `plt.gca().add_patch` as shown in the following code snippet. While the code itself work it is very long as there are 162 spectrum lines. My questions is, how can I loop this code to achieve the same outcome? Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib

input_observation = pd.read_csv("../data/obs_1.csv")
observation_wave = np.array((10 ** input_observation['wave'])/10)
observation_flux = np.array(input_observation['flux'])

tol = 1
window = tol*2

lines_labels = pd.read_excel("../lines/lines.xlsx") 

l1=lines_labels.iat[0,1]
l2=lines_labels.iat[1,1]
l3=lines_labels.iat[2,1]
l4=lines_labels.iat[3,1]
l5=lines_labels.iat[4,1]
l6=lines_labels.iat[5,1]
l7=lines_labels.iat[6,1]
l8=lines_labels.iat[7,1]
l9=lines_labels.iat[8,1]
l10=lines_labels.iat[9,1]
.
.
.
l152=fe_lines_labels.iat[151,1]
l153=fe_lines_labels.iat[152,1]
l154=fe_lines_labels.iat[153,1]
l155=lines_labels.iat[154,1]
l156=lines_labels.iat[155,1]
l157=lines_labels.iat[156,1]
l158=lines_labels.iat[157,1]
l159=lines_labels.iat[158,1]
l160=lines_labels.iat[[159,1]
l161=lines_labels.iat[160,1]
l162=lines_labels.iat[161,1]

plt.plot(observation_wave, observation_flux)

rect1=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l1-tol, 0),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect2=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l2-tol, 0),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect3=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l3-tol, 0),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect4=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l4-tol, 0),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect5=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l5-tol, 0),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect6=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l6-tol, 0),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect7=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l7-tol, 0),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect8=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l8-tol, 0),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect9=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l9-tol, 0),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect10=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l10-tol, 0),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
.
.
.
rect152=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l152-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect153=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l153-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect154=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l154-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect155=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l155-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect156=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l156-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect157=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l157-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect158=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l158-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect159=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l159-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect160=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l160-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect161=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l161-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)
rect162=matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((l162-tol),window, 2,color ='green',alpha=0.1)

plt.gca().add_patch(rect1)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect2)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect3)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect4)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect5)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect6)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect7)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect8)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect9)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect10)
.
.
.
plt.gca().add_patch(rect152)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect153)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect154)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect155)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect156)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect157)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect158)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect159)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect160)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect161)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect162)
```

Comment: You can create a loop `for i in range(162)`, inside the loop set `l=lines_labels.iat[i,1]` , then `rect=...(l-tol)...` and finally add the patch.

Comment: Use a list to hold your data. That will make your life sooooo much easier

Comment: Also, take a look at axvspan as a way to make patches

Comment: Thank you both very much. It is all sorted now. Your posts helped me with another loop I needed to write.